# Is there a way to paste a value in a different column to match the same row as the data entered?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to complete a unique task that requires combining the code of copying and pasting data from different sheets and pasting the data into the next empty row.

I am currently using this code to copy and paste a "kit" from *Update_kit* to *Create_assembly*. As new kits are found, the user can add the kit data to the next empty row in the table (4-10 rows of parts and their respective information) in Column C.

```
'Paste matching kit parts back into Create_assembly
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim db As Worksheet

Dim lCopy As Long
Dim lDest As Long

Dim lCopy2 As Long
Dim lDest2 As Long

Set db = Sheet10

  Sheets("Create_assembly").range("B6").Value = Sheets("Update_kit").range("B3").Value

  Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Update_kit") 'Copies table
  Set wsDest = Worksheets("Create_assembly") 'Pastes table

  lCopy = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
  lDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  'Copies any cell within the table
  wsCopy.range("B5:F" & lCopy).Copy
  wsDest.range("C" & lDest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

This line `Sheets("Create_assembly").range("B6").Value = Sheets("Update_kit").range("B3").Value` places the *Kit No.* from cell B3 in *Update_Kit* to *Create_assembly*. However, as I add new kits, cell B6 is replaced rather than adding the Kit No. to the next empty row in the table.

Also, instead of placing the *Kit No.* in the next empty row in Column B of *Create_Assembly* I would like it to match with its respective Kit. In the screenshot below, "LT-1 GOC" should be row 15 to match the parts that make up the kit in columns B-F.

[image]

This might be reallly confusing to follow but please ask away and I will try to clarify! Thanks in advance for the help.

***EDIT***

Below shows where the original kit data is stored (Kit_database). After the user makes a selection, whatever data is matched to the kit will be copied over to the next screenshot.
[image]

The kit information is dumped here and this is what is copied over to the *Create_assembly* page.
[image]

Comment: How would Excel know that it should be row 15? Do you have a lookup table somewhere, with all the relevant criteria a `KIT NO` should be accounted for?

Comment: Please see the edited post, I have added pictures to try to explain the sequence of events

Comment: So it's not really an unique task it seems, but rather a matter of `INDEX` and `MATCH`, or in VBA terms > `Range.Find` and `Range.Offset`. I must admit that I'm a little lost with where you want to go, but that might just be the right place to start your search =)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will definitely look into it